# Error attempting to create a pre-function in Kong

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to create a pre-function (serverless) in Kong:

`"cannot create 'plugins' entities when not using a database"`

I'm currently using a version 1.1.1 Alpine container and I have it configured for DB-less operation.  The documentation for the DB-less setup indicates that as long as the function doesn't try to connect to the database I should be fine, but the system itself is contradicting the documentation.  Right now, the script is just an import statement.

Is there something I may be missing regarding this or do I have to go back to use the database for configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in [kong documnet here](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/#read-only-admin-api):

> Since the only way to configure entities is via declarative config, the endpoints for CRUD operations on entities are effectively read-only in the Admin API when running Kong in DB-less mode.

You could only use GET method for Admin Api when running Kong in DB-less mode. So creating a plugin entity is with POST method will get error.

Want to add entities of kong? just follow [The Declarative Configuration Format](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/#the-declarative-configuration-format). Then import to Kong by HTTPie method ([Loading The Declarative Configuration File](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/#loading-the-declarative-configuration-file))

> $ http :8001/config config=@kong.yml

Comment: O.K.  It's looks like I may have missed the part about it being read-only.  I guess the challenge now is how to properly declare a serverless function in a YAML file.